# renderer and main process communication in electron - the right way

Tags: electron, communication

I'm a newbie to both Web tech and Electron!  I'm trying to build a desktop app with many windows and fields - including lookup/searches and retrieving data from a DB.
I believe I have most of what I need to get the job done except how to handle the communication between windows.  I.e. I need a dialog that displays a table of customers where the user selects a customer to return the data to the calling window. So I pass the search string to the lookup dialog which displays the customer list and in the dialog the user picks the customer and returns the primary key to the calling window (which will display the customer information). 
I have found several ways to do this on the web.  But I can't imagine that I need to keep a list of all the windows (about 90) and include a listener for each in the main.js (main process) to allow communication between the windows.  There must be a better way!!  Is there a simple way to setup a universal routine to process communication????

Answer (score 1):

If you're opening 90 windows you're going about this the wrong way. With Electron, every window runs in its own process. This means your app is going to have nearly 100 processes running which is going to be very slow on most machines.

Electron is a platform that brings web apps to the desktop. In a web app, if you want to show 90 windows you'd show them as HTML layers in a single browser window.

Comment: It is true that there are 90 forms/windows that can be opened.  But normally the user will open one - three windows.  Most of the time they will be one or two (other than running reports) of the forms.  The other forms/windows are mostly in support of the main three - four windows.  i.e. I need a form that will create class schedules that are available.  Then the other normally used forms/windows will use the data created by the support form that created the class schedule.

Comment: If you believe that three to four forms/windows (each window will contain 20 - 40 fields) is to much and I should seek a different solution - please say so!  I trying to replace a desktop app written in python and wxPython with Electron.

Comment: As windows are different processes the communication between them is not simple. In fact, the only way to communicate between windows is routed through the main process which make it even more complex. You should ideally try and make you app like a web app where multiple virtual windows are displayed within a single browser window. Then you don't have to do any tricky interprocess comms.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered several ways to open windows and add my html, css, and javascript to each of the windows.  I also have discovered a way to create a global var in the main process and have the other windows to retrieve the information from the global var.  So I guess I have avoided my concern of having to keep a list of the windows.  Still I'm struggling with Electron - almost nothing is straight forward. Or maybe I should say - very little matches my experience with desktop programming languages.
Johnf